# Why do two Random objects created with the same seed produce different results from hashcode()

Tags: java, random

I have a class that contains a `Random` object.  I use the `Random` object as part of a the overloaded `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` methods.  I discovered that two `java.util.Random` objects created with the same seed do not produce the same hash code nor does equals return true.

```
public class RandomTest extends TestCase {
    public void testRandom() throws Exception {

        Random r1 = new Random(1);
        Random r2 = new Random(1);


        assertEquals(r1.hashCode(), r2.hashCode()); //nope
        assertEquals(r1, r2); //nope
    }
}
```

I know the obvious work around is to use the seed plus nextSomething() for comparison(not perfect but it should work well enough).  So my question is Why are two objects of type Random created with the same seed and at the same iteration not equal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `java.util.Random` class doesn't override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, so hash code from `Object` class is called, returning an address in memory for the object. So 2 different Random objects have 2 different hashCodes as they are actually different objects.

Comment: And this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Shouldn't they override it though?  I am unfamiliar with contract of library classes when it comes to those operations but it is certainly standard practice for developers to override them.

Comment: I suppose people who wrote this class didn't think it's useful to compare Random objects or to use them as HashMap keys.

Comment: This is primarily a testing situation.  It is useful to be able to determine if the same pseudo random generator will produce the same results as the another.  It allows you to repeat long sequences (like transaction streams) and compare the results to see if there is drift. I think I am able to override the Class and create my own comparisons though so...

Comment: I just noticed that the current seed is not publicly available.  I am now wondering if this is actually because exposing the seed would allow a potential security breach and by extension, overriding hashCode and equals might also allow a similar breach.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson The initial seed may not even be *stored* (take a look at the source of java.util.Random), it isn't used "as is".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are confusing the `Random` object with the results. The `Random` object is a random number generator, and not a random number. Comparing them makes no sense. Whatever you are trying to do should probably be accomplished a different way.

Comment: It is both useful and necessary to compare streams of pseudo random numbers without knowing the fixed end of use.  That is after all the whole purpose behind the class.  Otherwise, you can just use Math.random or w/e.